# Flutterfire Package Dependency errors on MacOs build

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-packages

I have just transferred (via GitHub) my app repo from my WIn 11 machine to my Mac Mini M1 (Ventura) to start testing on iOS. All was going fairly well until I get this message when doing a pod install:

```
[15:20]
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Database":
  In Podfile:
    firebase_database (from .symlinks/plugins/firebase_database/ios) was resolved to 10.0.9, which depends on
      Firebase/Database (= 10.3.0) flutter_geofire (from .symlinks/plugins/flutter_geofire/ios) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      GeoFire (~> 4.0) was resolved to 4.1.0, which depends on
        Firebase/Database (~> 6.0)
```

I have tried all the answers I have seen on SO that relate to this but to no avail.

The app builds fine for Android on Win11 but gives the above dependencies error when building for iOS.

This is the command sequence I use to clean the environment on the Mac:

```
Delete pubspec.lock
Change to iOS directory
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf Podfile.lock 
rm -rf ~/Library/Flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ 
pod cache clean --all 
flutter clean 
flutter pub get 
pod repo update 
pod install
```

Anyone else experienced this with flutterfire packages? Any advice welcome. :-)

I am trying down-versioning some of them, but as you know that is a minefield and not the end solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete Podfile.lock file, then run pod install once again. If that does not help, try to upgrade flutter packages using flutter pub upgrade. Also pass —repo-update to pod install.

Comment: Thanks very much for responding. These are the commands I ran, it seems to be more about the Flutterfire packages: Delete pubspec.lock

Then change to iOS directory and: 

rm -rf Pods
rm -rf Podfile.lock
rm -rf ~/Library/Flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
pod cache clean --all 
flutter clean
flutter pub get
pod repo update
pod install

Comment: I do not remember having problems with flutterfire packages, using them recently in an iOS project. Can you provide part of your pubspec.yaml

Comment: thanks for your response. Seems I was chasing the wrong error...the GeoFire package was the one complaining and it was basically my fault for not setting up the podfile properly, as per their Readme.md. Fixed now.